# Identifying an Actor in Star Wars: A New Hope's Tantive IV Boarding Scene?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, actor-identification

In *Star Wars: A New Hope*, as Darth Vader prepares to board Tantive IV, the security team of the ship assembles in an attempt to repel the empire's boarding party. There is a close-up shot of a particular actor, the first one prominently featured in the movie, even though he is essentially a background character. What is the name of this actor?

It's cool to think your face will be seen by millions, even hundreds of years from now.

[image]

Comment: "It's cool to think your face will be seen by millions, even hundreds of years from now" — it's cool to think that, but I'm not sure millions of people today are watching movies from 1923, so I don't know if the idea applies here.

Comment: The movie industry was in its nascent stage back then, but if we go a decade or so later I have no doubt that the Wizard of Oz or Citizen Kane will be seen by millions of people post 2040. Star Wars is nearly 50 years old, and it's staying power seems pretty established to me at this point -- perhaps greater than both the aforementioned movies. I'd be quite surprised if it's forgotten by 2079.

Comment: Movies [were a bit quiet back then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1923_in_film), I'll give you.

Comment: Relevant XKCD: https://xkcd.com/1262/

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Well, I am fairly sure millions does at least know of likes of Charlie Chaplin or Buster Keaton

Comment: And in fairness, in a world of 8 or 9 billion people, you only need 0.025% of the population to have 2 million people.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The character is [Pello Scrambas](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Pello_Scrambas) played by the actor [Eddie Eddon](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0248863/)

Comment: _Batman_, _Superman_, a dozen James Bond movies and the original _Star Wars_. That’s **quite** the CV!

Comment: He was principally a stuntman, which was appropriate for this role.

Comment: Funny that the actors IMDB profile pic is from exactly this movie scene.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: It’s most likely the scene where he is better seen.

Comment: @PierrePaquette I've seen that scene and can confirm it is a scene in which he is seen very clearly.